# Expected user_string to be a string, null given in C:\xampp... on line 1662

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently I've had this warning error message on my wordpress:

> Warning: hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string, null given in C:\xampp3\htdocs\Plurielles\wordpress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1662
>
> Warning: hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string, null given in C:\xampp3\htdocs\Plurielles\wordpress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1668

It disabled a lot of features on my website (add an image and a lot more....) 
I've been looking in the php file for these two lines, and they are:

line 1662 :

```
if ( hash_equals( $expected, $nonce ) ) {
    return 1;
}
```

line 1668 :

```
if ( hash_equals( $expected, $nonce ) ) {
    return 2;
}
```

Do you know how I could fix it? I'm a newbie in PHP so I apologize if this is really easy to solve (you could throw me rock).

Comment: You need a string to pass to hash_equals(). https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/hash_equals/

Comment: Thank you very much but do you know how I can modify this ? Where I declare my has_equals is a string ?

Comment: you're welcome. Sorry, but I have never worked with that function before and it seems to be a common problem. I Google'd it and found just that; a string needs to be passed, so there is something you are not doing in your code somewhere. Example: `$string = "this is a string";` would be valid, but `$string = 12345;` would not be a "string" but an integer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help I found on the website, I've found a solution and I post it here for people who would be in same situation than me.

You juste have to use a `settype ($variable ="string")` 
in my case :
`settype ($expected ="string")`
`settype ($nonce="string")`
On wordpress that should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
settype ($expected, "string");
settype ($nonce, "string");
```